# Self-Opening application (creating lockscreen)

Tags: java, android, background-process, lockscreen

I'm creating lockscreen for my phone. I'm looking for some ways to open one of my app activities when user push power button (when screen is disabled) and when he try to open one of earlier specified apps. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943407/create-an-android-lock-screen

Comment: @ShivamVerma ok, but in fact this link didn't answer my question

Comment: If you check out the source code  listed there, it actually does answer your question. You just need to look for it.

Comment: there are no comments, no explanation, no help from author in this example. I've seen this code, but I've still no idea how and why it works.