# How to make our own lock screen in android instead of default lock screen

Tags: java, android, boot, lockscreen

I have an idea of creating my own phone lock app similar to android pattern lock. I need to display or start my app whenever the phone boots/restarts/phone, lock/phone, and unlock. I don't know how to make the app appear instead of default lock screen and to hide the default lock screen.
So my questions are:

1. How to display or start my app instead of default lock screen
2. What is

   ```
   getWindow().addFlags(
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | 
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
   ```

How this is helpful?

3. What is

   ```
   public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction() != null) {
               if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
               Intent s = new  Intent(context,ViewPagerMainActivity.class);
               s.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               context.startActivity(s);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

How this is helpful?

4. How do you show the home page after my app finishes its work?

Comment: You may check my answer, I think will help you achieve what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/28603790/3300883

Answer (score 22):

Codes that you have used in point 2 should be used as answer of your question 1. Reference is [Android activity over default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen).

For question 2, see these relevant links:

- [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)
- [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)
- [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
- [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)

Before answering your question 3,i would like to ask you, do you have knowledge about [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)? In short it is-

> A broadcast receiver (short receiver) is an Android component which
>   allows you to register for system or application events. All
>   registered receivers for an event are notified by the Android runtime
>   once this event happens.
>
> For example, applications can register for the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
>   system event which is fired once the Android system has completed the
>   boot process.

Now come to your question 4, you can show home page programmatically by this code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Refer: [Going to home screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically)

And last of all i would like to provide you some links that may help you to make a custom lock screen:

- [Creating an Android Lock Screen App.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943407/create-an-android-lock-screen)
- [Any tutorial for customize lock screen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889855/any-tutorial-for-customize-lock-screen-in-android)
- [Making Customize Lock Screen](http://playingwithandroid.blogspot.com/2012/07/making-customize-lock-screen.html)
- [Implement lock screen in Android](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/01/tutorial-71-implement-lock-screen-in-android/)