# How to show custom UI / widget on Lock Screen in Android

Tags: java, android, react-native, lockscreen, lockscreenwidget

I have a requirement to show a customised screen over/on the lock screen in android. logically I want to show a screen (an activity) when phone is locked.

[[image]]

I have tried multiple ways to achieve this functionality but no luck yet.
some links which I have followed are :

1. https://github.com/ShakeebM/Android-LockScreen
2. [Create custom lockscreen for android 4.0 or above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911049/create-custom-lockscreen-for-android-4-0-or-above?rq=1)
3. [show web site on Android lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647259/show-web-site-on-android-lock-screen/44881042#44881042)
4. [Creating custom LockScreen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983462/creating-custom-lockscreen-in-android)
5. https://github.com/Kirk-Str/LockScreenApp

As of now I am able to show a custom screen over the lock screen when app is in foreground state but when app is in background/killed state not able to show the custom screen over the lock screen. Please suggest me what I am missing in my code snippet.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lockscreen">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".sample2.screen.LockScreenActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="false"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".sample2.utils.LockscreenService" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".sample2.utils.LockscreenIntentReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LockscreenService Class:**

```
package com.example.lockscreen.sample2.utils;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.example.lockscreen.R;


public class LockscreenService extends Service {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    // Register for Lockscreen event intents
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("LockScreen ::: ","onStartCommand");
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        mReceiver = new LockscreenIntentReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        startForeground();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    // Run service in foreground so it is less likely to be killed by system
    private void startForeground() {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Running")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentIntent(null)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        startForeground(9999,notification);
    }

    // Unregister receiver
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

**LockscreenIntentReceiver Class:**

```
package com.example.lockscreen.sample2.utils;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.example.lockscreen.sample2.screen.LockScreenActivity;


public class LockscreenIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Handle actions and display Lockscreen
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            start_lockscreen(context);
        }
    }

    // Display lock screen
    private void start_lockscreen(Context context) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mIntent);
    }
}
```

**LockScreenActivity Class**:

```
package com.example.lockscreen.sample2.screen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.lockscreen.R;
import com.example.lockscreen.sample2.utils.LockscreenService;
import com.example.lockscreen.sample2.utils.LockscreenUtils;


public class LockScreenActivity extends Activity implements
        LockscreenUtils.OnLockStatusChangedListener {

    // User-interface
    private Button btnUnlock;

    // Member variables
    private LockscreenUtils mLockscreenUtils;

    // Set appropriate flags to make the screen appear over the keyguard
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        this.getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        );

        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        );

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lockscreen);

        init();
        // unlock screen in case of app get killed by system
        if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("kill")
                && getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kill") == 1) {
            enableKeyguard();
            unlockHomeButton();
        }
       

            try {
                // disable keyguard
                disableKeyguard();

                // lock home button
                lockHomeButton();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"lockHomeButton startService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // start service for observing intents
                startService(new Intent(this, LockscreenService.class));

                // listen the events get fired during the call
                StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

    }

    private void init() {
        mLockscreenUtils = new LockscreenUtils();
        btnUnlock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUnlock);
        btnUnlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // unlock home button and then screen on button press
                unlockHomeButton();
            }
        });
    }

    // Handle events of calls and unlock screen if necessary
    private class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    unlockHomeButton();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    // Don't finish Activity on Back press
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }

    // Handle button clicks
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
                || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    // handle the key press events here itself
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
                || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Lock home button
    public void lockHomeButton() {
        mLockscreenUtils.lock(LockScreenActivity.this);
    }

    // Unlock home button and wait for its callback
    public void unlockHomeButton() {
        mLockscreenUtils.unlock();
    }

    // Simply unlock device when home button is successfully unlocked
    @Override
    public void onLockStatusChanged(boolean isLocked) {
        if (!isLocked) {
            unlockDevice();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unlockHomeButton();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void disableKeyguard() {
        KeyguardManager mKM = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKL = mKM.newKeyguardLock("IN");
        mKL.disableKeyguard();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void enableKeyguard() {
        KeyguardManager mKM = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKL = mKM.newKeyguardLock("IN");
        mKL.reenableKeyguard();
    }

    //Simply unlock device by finishing the activity
    private void unlockDevice()
    {
        finish();
    }

}
```

Please help me how can I achieve this?