# Disable the Home button on latest version of Android

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-homebutton

I'm trying to implement a Lock Screen application and I spent more than 20 hours on how to disable the home button. I have tested many codes sample available on the Internet (like answer to [how to make our own lock screen in android instead of default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598612/how-to-make-our-own-lock-screen-in-android-instead-of-default-lock-screen)) but non of them are working on the latest versions of Android (min is Marshmallow) and seems outdated. How can I disable the home button for the latest version of Android?

Comment: What do you want?some unclearly part.do you want to disable home button and other system buttons in android?please give the answer 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: No, I want display an activity on the top of all windows from a service and would act as lock screen, but pressing the home button minimize making the app pointless, so I want to disable the home button. may some has better solution.

Comment: Try setting your app as a launcher.Then when home button is clicked your app will be called, keeping your app open.