# Provide custom lock screen method

Tags: android, lockscreen, lockscreenwidget

I'm looking for a way to create a custom lock screen method, but was unable to find any official informations about in the API docs. Stock android currently ships with different methods such as PIN, password, pattern, face lock.. so I wondered if it is possible to create one without modifying the system itself.

Please note this is not a duplicate of the hundreds of "custom lock screen" questions here on SO, as I'm asking specifically about **lock screen methods**, not for creating a replacement.

**Edit**

Currently crawling through the android source where I found a few classes that *MIGHT* be interesting:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/a6ed1b9547dcd592031a415739cc7e672c068f7c/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/a6ed1b9547dcd592031a415739cc7e672c068f7c/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible unless you create your own custom lock screen. You can build one pretty easily though with the [Adenda](http://adendamedia.com) SDK. Sign up for it on their website, they usually respond pretty quickly

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only answer is to do a replacement such as this OS answer:
[Creating an Android Lock Screen App.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943407/create-an-android-lock-screen)

But after reading the source of the github repo linked..the

API docs you want is KeyguardManager...

android.app.KeyguardManager;

javadoc is here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html

this method:

public void exitKeyguardSecurely (KeyguardManager.OnKeyguardExitResult callback)

is depreciated above api 12 use the flags mentioned in the javadoc instead